# why is function name repeated in haskell? (newbie)

Tags: haskell

Why is the function name repeated in

example:

```
lucky :: (Integral a) => a -> String  
lucky 7 = "LUCKY NUMBER SEVEN!"  
lucky x = "Sorry, you're out of luck, pal!"
```

when should I not be repeating function name? what is the meaning of it?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is pattern match in action.

I will show you another example:

```
test 1 = "one"
test 2 = "two"
test 3 = "three"
```

Demo in ghci:

```
ghci> test 1
"one"
ghci> test 2
"two"
ghci> test 3
"three"
ghci> test 4
"*** Exception: Non-exhaustive patterns in function test
```

So, when you call any function, the runtime system will try to match
the input with the defined function. So a call to `test 3` will
initially check `test 1` and since `1` is not equal to `3`, it will
move on to the next definition. Again since `2` is not equal to `3`,
it will move to the next defintion. In the next definiton since `3` is
equal to `3` it will return `"three"` String back. When you try to
pattern match something, which doesn't exist at all, the program
throws the exception.

Answer (score 4):

This kind of pattern matching can be transformed to a `case` statement (and indeed, that's what compilers will normally do!):

```
lucky' n = case n of
    7 -> "LUCKY NUMBER SEVEN!"
    x -> "Sorry, you're out of luck, pal!"
```

Because the `x` isn't really used, you'd normally write `_ -> "Sorry, ..."` instead.

Note that this is *not*<sup>2</sup> the same as

```
lucky'' n = if n==7 then ...
```

Equality comparison with `(==)` is in general more expensive<sup>1</sup> than pattern matching, and also comes out uglier.

---

<sup>1</sup> Why it's more expensive: suppose we have a big data structure. To determine that they are equal, the program will need to dig through *both entire structures*, make sure really all branches are equal. However, if you *pattern match*, you will just compare a small part you're interested in right now.

<sup>2</sup> *Actually*, it is the same in the case, but just because the compiler has a particular trick for pattern matching on numbers: it rewrites it with `(==)`. This is really special for `Num` types and not true for anything else. (Except if you use [the `OverloadedStrings` extension](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#overloaded-strings).)

Comment: That's a pretty weird trick. It makes a lot of sense for strings (with the GHC overloaded strings extension) and *exact* numbers, but not so much for inexact ones. Haskell, unlike Scheme, does not recognize the distinction between exact and inexact numbers, so it ends up supporting pattern matching on floating point, which seems a bit strange.

Comment: (Sorry I happened to delete my previous comment *just* as you replied to it—I did some experimentation earlier and figured out what the deal was).

Comment: @dfeuer: never mind, comments are transient anyway... Agree, that about inexact numbers is not nice. But why would you write a pattern matching for a float in the first place? — What would be nice is patterns of a form like `f (3.14...) = "Close to pi"; f _ = "Nothing to do with pi"`, but that would need an even wonkier transformation.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're looking at [learn you a haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions). After that example, it says that

> When you call lucky, the patterns will be checked from top to bottom and when it conforms to a pattern, the corresponding function body will be used.

So the first line indicates the type of the function, and later lines are patterns to check. Each line has the function name so the compiler knows you're still talking about the same function.

Think of it this way: When you write the expression `lucky (a+b)` or whatever, the compiler will attempt to replace `lucky (a+b)` with the first thing before the `=` in the function definition that "fits." So if `a=3` and `b=4`, you get this series of replacements:

```
lucky (a+b) =
lucky (3+4) =
--pattern matching occurs...
lucky 7 =
"LUCKY NUMBER SEVEN!"
```

This is part of what makes Haskell so easy to reason about in practice; you get a system that works similarly to math.

Comment: Note that arithmetic pattern matching is frowned upon because it doesn't follow the usual pattern matching rules.

Comment: @Cubic The `lucky (a+b)` I wrote is intended to be an expression, rather than a pattern. I'll edit to be more clear.

Answer (score 2):

That definition of `lucky` uses "pattern matching", and equals (in this case)

```
lucky :: (Integral a) => a -> String  
lucky a = if a == 7
    then "LUCKY NUMBER SEVEN!"
    else "Sorry, you're out of luck, pal!"
```

Comment: For number types, pattern matching and `(==)` are indeed equivalent, but that's _not_ true in general. Pattern matching is preferrable, either with multiple function clauses or with a `case` statement.